# Solve sudoku field recursively in Java

Tags: java, recursion, sudoku

I am trying to make a sudoku game.

I have a multi-dimensional array of 9by9 (`this.model[9][9]`).

I have made some function `checkRow`, `checkCol`, and `checkValue` to check validity horizontally, vertically, and in the 9 (smaller) boxes.

I have created a function `tryValue` which tests if a certain value is valid in a specific cell (given by row `i` and col `j`):

```
public boolean tryValue(int val, int i, int j) {
    // check validity of row
    if (!checkRow(val, i)) {
        return false;
    }

    // check validity of column
    if (!checkCol(val, j)) {
        return false;
    }

    // check validity of box
    if (!checkBox(val, i, j)) {
        return false;
    }

    // insert value
    this.model[i][j] = val;

    // could not break function before, so we assume it is valid
    return true;
}
```

Now I am trying to solve the sudoku by recursion. I have tried doing this:

```
public static void solve(Field f, int i, int j) throws SolvedException {
    if (i >= Field.SIZE) {
        // we are done (base case in recursion)
    } else if (j >= Field.SIZE) {
        solve(f, i + 1, 0);
    } else {
        // if empty cell
        if (f.isEmpty(i, j)) {
            // try all values (i.e. values from 1 to 9)
            for (int k=1; k<=9; k++) {
                // if value is valid, insert value
                if (f.tryValue(k, i, j)) {
                    // juhu!
                }
            }
        }

        // continue recursion
        solve(f, i, j + 1);
    }
}
```

but I go through all values from 1 to 9 with

```
// try all values (i.e. values from 1 to 9)
for (int k=1; k<=9; k++) {
    // if value is valid, insert value
    if (f.tryValue(k, i, j)) {
        ...
```

which is obviously wrong since I can't just check all values, but I need to do a more clever check of values.

I guess I might need to create a temporary array of values, so I can rewrite the guesses of values until it is possible to solve the sudoku.

So I probably need something like

```
while (tryValue(k, i, j)) {
    ...
```

Comment: Remember, the first tip under  [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is "Search, and research".  There are many Sudoku solutions on the internet, and quite a few in Java.  Stack Overflow has a good selection.  How is it that *all* of those leave you without *any* viable way to implement your next step?  That should be part of your question focus.